# Swift: Convert UITextField input to string and split string at certain character

Tags: ios, string, swift

I am trying to convert the text inside a UITextField into a string so that I can use the method "componentsSeperatedByString(".") on the string in order to turn it into an array. But I keep receiving an error that UITextField does not have member "componentsSeperatedByString". Any advice? Thanks

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!



    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!



    //Login function. Drag Down keyboard after clicking login
    @IBAction func Login(sender: AnyObject) {
        username.resignFirstResponder()
        password.resignFirstResponder()

        var username_array: [String] = username.componentsSeperatedByString(".")


}
}
```

Comment: username is a textfield. Shouldn't it be username.text and then call username_text.componentsSeperatedByString(".")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `username` is a `UITextField` not `String`. Try this:

```
var username_array: [String] = username.text.componentsSeperatedByString(".")
```